Unable to rebase git repository when running inside a devcontainer
Whenever I try to rebase within a devcontainer running on a Mac, I get the following error:
vscode ➜ /workspaces/project (feature/some-feature) $ git rebase main
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        src/main.ts
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
hint: Could not execute the todo command
hint:
hint:     pick ab4cbe7d8997937d709d8773b8b37b153a1e2d09 wip
hint:
hint: It has been rescheduled; To edit the command before continuing, please
hint: edit the todo list first:
hint:
hint:     git rebase --edit-todo
hint:     git rebase --continue
vscode ➜ /workspaces/project (6b4b467) $

After which I have to git rebase --abort and do the exact same command outside of the container, in the macOS command line.
This makes it very cumbersome to develop inside a dev container, as I have to switch back and forth between it and the macOS CLI.

There seems to be some issue with the way inodes are managed in Docker Desktop on the Mac and git. The inodes change during the rebase operation which causes git to think the files were changed.
The check found here causes the changed flag to be set, which causes verify_uptodate_1 to report a file change, which in turn fails the checkout
The check can be disabled by setting the core.checkStat config value to minimal. I run this in my devcontainer postCreateCommand and the problem is gone.
git config set --system core.checkStat minimal
